Google App: Transferred App - Google Cloud Functions showing errors
I recently transferred my app from my personal Google developer account to my organization developer account. My android app uses Google Cloud functions like pub/sub and service agents. Since the transfer, I've had errors with my cloud functions. I get 401 unauthorized errors for a pub/sub scheduled function and I get a resource name error for my Firestore trigger function. When one transfers apps, do the Cloud Functions permissions invalidate and I have to create them from scratch?
I have tried redeploying the functions several times after the app transfer was complete. I have also added the service account email as a user with the required permissions in the organization developer account's Google Play Console. Still didn't fix it. Looking for any push in the right direction please and thank you!

Go to the Play Console for your app. Navigate to "App Signing" -> "Manage Account Access" Add the newly created service account email as a user with "Manage App Signing" access.

Create a New Service Account in the Organization Account from GCP IAM console add roles like:
Pub/Sub: Pub/Sub Publisher, Subscriber, and Admin (for scheduled functions) Firestore: Cloud Firestore Admin (for trigger functions)
Also you may need to update the Cloud Function Configuration with the correct PUB/SUB & Firestore for the new service account.

Kindly refer to the official GCP trouble shooting document may help to resolve your issue.

Did you have time to check my above comments? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further. What should I do when someone answers my question?

Hi there, thank you kindly for your reply. My cloud function that was getting the 401 error resolved itself, which I believe is attributed to adding the service account email to the play console 'Users and Permissions' list. At the time I wrote the question it was quite recent (day of) that I put the email in. Perhaps the system had to propagate the new addition.
My last cloud function still shows logs in that:
Error: Resource name 'projects/lockchain-xxxxx/topics/topic_name' is not valid.

Okay so fixed. Seems like adding the service account email to the new Google Play console 'Users and Permissions' helped, but it took up to a day to propagate. Then I didn't receive the 401 error for one of my functions.
The other error was an old error I encountered before but simply forgot. I was getting:
"message": "Change of function trigger type or event provider is not allowed",
"status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
I was trying to update the function, but Firebase detected that the trigger type for this function has changed. Cloud Functions do not allow modifying the type of trigger (e.g., from HTTP to Firestore or Pub/Sub) for an already deployed function. I deleted the Cloud Function and redeployed. Worked. Turned out to be unrelated to my App transfer.
Thank you
